# Get and evaluate every character inside an element for brace matching

Tags: javascript

```
<div id = "board>
    <div>{abc</div>
    <div>def</div>
    <div>ghi}</div>
</div>
```

I want compare every char inside the div **at their position** and do something when if found **{** or **}**

Im aware that this is possible by wrapping every char within `<span></span>`

Is there a way to do this without using a span? I will use this for brace matching of my code editor project. this is what i've done using span wrapping, but it is so slow..

```
$exceedingInlineDiv = $('#board_code_dup > div').eq(x);
if( $exceedingInlineDiv.text() == ''){
    var chars = '<span> <br> </span>';
    $exceedingInlineDiv.html(chars);
}

else{
    var chars = jQuery.map($exceedingInlineDiv.text().split(''), function(c) {
        return '<span>' + c + '</span>';
    });
    $exceedingInlineDiv.html(chars.join(''));
}//else
```

Comment: Depends on, what exactly means "`do something`". You can remove `{,}`s or change them to an other character(s), but if you need to apply CCS only to some characters in a `div`, that's not possible.

Comment: i'll be using this for brace matching of my code editor project, i need to highlight them. I've asked this because im having trouble with the slow speed of span wrapping them :) tnx

Comment: You could create an array of the text content of `#board`. With this array it's easy to make brace matchig and wrap only matching braces within spans. I'd suggest you to add the brace matching thing into you question, it might be reopened, and you would get a proper answer for this.

Comment: applying your suggestion... the problem is how will i know the position of { or } so that they will be the only char to be wrapped?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but maybe you want something like this:

```
var board = document.getElementById("board"),
    divs = board.getElementsByTagName("div"),
    texts = [], i = 0;

for (; i < divs.length; i++)
    texts.push(divs[i].innerHTML);

// texts => ["{abc", "def", "ghi}"]
```

Comment: i'll be using it for brace matching of my code editor project. i need to take note of the position where i found { or }